# Working flow of XMPP, SIP and Web RTC

Tags: xmpp, webrtc, protocols, sip, instant-messaging

I am eager to know the working flow of the XMPP, SIP and Web RTC. 
I have researched a lot about this, but frankly saying couldn't get a proper idea of their working flow.

I want to know which one is best and why? Are they all using the same kind of architecture or workflow?

Please help me to get the clear picture of it.

Answer (score 2):

On a humble note you are trying to cover many oceans in one stroke. I would like to help in simplest possible manner :

XMPP, SIP and webRTC are all related to IP telephony and communications world. Communication world is majorly categorized in two parts : 1.Signaling 2.Media

XMPP and SIP are categorized as signaling protocols ie the type of protocols which controls and govern media related features while webRTC is one type of media protocol which actually exchanges communication  data securely,adaptively and seamlessly based on the parameters exchanged during any signaling protocol.

Depending upon the features like simple call,call forwarding,call hold, SIP trunking etc call flow differs but in general difference remain the same. For more details kindly refer the RFCs of all three protocols.